# SSO - Microsoft Graph API - Azure Personal Access Token

Tags: reactjs, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a project where I need to access the outlook users of my organization using the Graph API, but I don't want to register my app to **Azure**.

But I have PAT ( Personal Access Token ), So my question is that is it possible to get the details from graph API using the PAT.

like using the PAT instead of Access Token....

I have tried to replace the access token with the Personal access token but getting error like **InvalidAccessToken**.

Comment: Please clarify the ask, if you need to get details of other users in the tenant then you cannot use the personal account or any other account for that matter you may have to use the application permissions by registering the app on azure AD unless you are the admin of the tenant.

Comment: Thank You for your response...
Actually I am trying to get the Access Token from Azure Ad without registering my application in azure. End goal is to used Graph API with that Access Token.

I have Personal Access Token of Azure, so is it possible that I can get the Access Token using PAT...